# Negative values distance model between 2 sets

Tags: distance-functions, distance, similarities

I have two sets, $A$ and $B$, containing **string** values.

I am trying to model the relationship between sets $A$ and $B$ by computing the following distance:
$d = \frac{ \mid A \mid + \mid B \mid- \mid A \cap B \mid}{ \mid A \mid + \mid B \mid}$

$ d = \ [0,...,1 \ ] $

The more $A$ and $B$ are similar the closer $d$ is to $0$. The more different $A$ and $B$ are the closer $d$ is to $1$.

I added a threshold $\sigma = 0.5$ so if $ d <\sigma \Longrightarrow e = d + \sigma$ and if $ d >= \sigma \Longrightarrow e = d - 1 - \sigma$. This way $e = \ [-1,...,1 \ ] $ What I am doing is mapping $d$ to $e$.

What I want to ask is if there a **distance** that gives a negative value if the two are not enough similar and a positive value if the two sets are closer to each other. This value should also be between $e = \ [-1,...,1 \ ]$.

This way I can get rid of the **threshold** $\sigma$.

The more similar the sets are to each other, the closer $e$ is to $1$ and less similar the sets are to each other the closer $e$ is to $-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have very generic suggestions, but without knowing how you want to use the metric, this is the best I can come up with.

A couple of options:

1) Your description reminds me of Silhouette index used in clustering. You can probably define a similar metric for your purpose.

3) Jaccard Index of Similarity (actually J(A,B)-1 for your case).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @shyamupa. Actually i was looking for a similar function. The silhouette index is really interesting. I'll read about and understand how it works. i'll post a question if I didn't understand it well.

Thank you

Comment: Concering the jaccard index values will be between [-1,1] right?

Comment: Not the jaccard index as is, but you can modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: $J(A,B) = \frac{ \mid A \cap B \mid}{ \mid A \cup B \mid} - 1$

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to ask is if there a distance that gives a negative value if the two are not enough similar and a positive value if the two sets are closer to each other $\ldots$

Short answer - no. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#General_case):

> $\ldots$ In mathematics, in particular geometry, a distance function on a given set M is a function d: M×M → R, where R denotes the set of real numbers, that satisfies the following conditions: **d(x,y) ≥ 0**, and d(x,y) = 0 if and only if x = y. $\ldots$

I'm not sure what the name of kind of function exactly you're looking for (maybe just similarity measure), but you won't find it googling for distances. Also, if you're intending to use this function as part of any algorithm which specifies it needs a **distance**, allowing negative values can make it break horribly. It doesn't look like you are, but still, beware.